# How to create activity indicator loading alert in a black transparent square?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want to create an alert like on the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its a 3rd party

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'

in pods and

let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
        loadingNotification.labelText = "Loding..."

MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbprogresshud
https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: great if it solved your issue please mark as correct answered